# Bluetooth mouse cursor often disappears from screen or just stuck

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, bluetooth, iwlwifi

I just bought a microsoft designer bluetooth mouse recently. It connects ok to my Kubuntu 16.10 but the cursor often disappears from the screen or just stuck for a few seconds. It seems that something is interfering the mouse connection.

Is this common issue on Ubuntu with a bluetooth mouse?

I am using microsoft bluetooth keyboard too and there is no problem at all.

Or is it a problem from the mouse itself.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:9010]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 i have edited my question with the output. have a look. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixable I guess. You need to disable `bt_coex` option in `iwlwifi` since it does not work well. Wi-Fi randomly blocks the BT.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

and reboot.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i have just done that and will let u know how it goes.

Comment: it seems ok so far. no more disappearing or getting stuck. thanks!

Comment: sorry. it is not working actually. I get the same output when I run this `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`. cursor still `sticky` often. so i uncheck this answer just in case...

Comment: It may be related to this bug: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190831

Comment: The solution outlined the link that follows worked for me. http://r3dux.org/2017/01/how-to-fix-intel-8260-rev-3a-slow-rubbish-wireless-issues-in-linux/